wired instead of wireless in ubuntu 24.04
I had a recent distribution update from 22.04 to 24.04 on my desktop computer. In the SETTINGS, for Network the only option is for WIRED and the caption shows CABLE UNPLUGGED. In 22.04 I had a wireless connection to the internet. How do I have the option of Wireless connection in 24.04?

Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; mokutil --sb

I'm not that good at Linux nor Ubuntu, but here's what I'd do.
Try unblocking the Wi-Fi adapter, like this $ sudo rfkill unblock wifi
If that doesn't work try upgrading your system, like this sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
You could also find out your Network Card by typing this, lspci | grep Network then searh for answers online.
If even that doesn't work the only thing I can think of is to reinstall Ubuntu, but make sure to backup your stuff before you do that.
Here's where I got my answers at:
Why is the Enable Wireless button greyed out and unselectable? and https://thealmightypush.blogspot.com/2020/11/solved-wifi-adapter-not-found-ubuntu.html
